# How to find voltage across X and Y?

Tags: circuit-analysis

This is the schematic diagram of the circuit [image]

This is a homework question , which belongs to mcq type

It is about   finding voltage across X and Y?

Is there voltage between x and y ? I wonder if there is a voltage across x and y, because they aren't connected , so how can a current flow ?

But non of the answers given are zero,so what is the way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried calculating the currents yet?

Comment: Do I need to use Kirchhoff's loop rule for that?

Comment: Hint: The resistor connected to node Y is irrelevant.

Comment: @ Matt Young : Why it is irrelevant?

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess as you said, there is no current flowing through that branch, so that resistor does not drop any voltage. Therefore, you can treat it like it's not even there

Comment: Think of it this way: You're actually measuring the voltage across the bottom 50 ohm resistor. All you need to do is find the total current through the loop, and use Ohm's Law to find how much voltage that resistor drops

Comment: It means I can neglect 50 ohm resistor in series y ?

Comment: Yes you can. Again, as you mentioned, that branch is open, so no current will flow through it. If no current flows, then that resistor wont' drop any voltage, meaning that the voltage at point Y is the same as the voltage at the left-connection of the resistor

Comment: Is it because there is no current would flowing  through that resistor , or any other thing ?

Comment: Current IS flowing through the outer loop, so you WILL have a non-zero voltage between X and Y. But no current is flowing through the resistor connected to Y, so according to Ohm's Law, V = 0amps * 50 ohms, thus V dropped by that resistor is 0volts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way: Since the middle branch (containing the "top" 50 ohm resistor) is open, no current will flow through it. Therefore, you're dealing with a single series loop, and you're actually measuring the voltage across the "bottom" 50 ohm resistor. All you need to do is find the total current through the main loop, and use Ohm's Law to find how much voltage that "bottom" resistor drops

Comment: Okay I found the answer! total current is 0.1 A and voltage across 5V(=0.1 x50)

Comment: Great work! If this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so that future viewers of this thread will know it worked =)

Comment: Okay , I mark it